# how to setup redlock to a chat apllication

Tags: node.js, next.js, redis, chat

I've been working on a chat app using Next.js 13 to create a waiting queue for clients who are waiting for other clients. The chats will always be one-to-one and will connect randomly. However, I've noticed there could be concurrency issues when two clients try to connect with the same client. While looking for a solution, I came across the [redlock package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redlock) package, and I've been trying to use it. But I don't know how to use it as I have no experience working with Redis. Can someone show me some pseudo code or give me some tips about working with it?